# How to make collage in shape for iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photo

I want many collages in some particular shape like heart shape, star shape, etc... 
Can any one tell me how can I do this programmatically in my iPhone app with objective c?

Comment: Yes ,For making a collage ull need images, add these images into the UIView and then do what you want.... Can you please make your question a bit more clearer ? What do u actually want ??

Comment: Yes , I have done that .thanks but can you tell me how can I put all images in one shape at random position? I want shape collages like this app. http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/shape-collage/id436917115?mt=8

Comment: For doing this you would have to use UIGestures or UITouches and u should have multiple images which you can move according to the touch and place them in a collage... I can explain but itll b long ... shud i explain more ?

Comment: hey thanks man. I got all images in scroll and one by one I can add it in a view and also can rotate it,move it and zoom it. I just want to know that after selecting images how can I put it in a shape together at random position? as in the app I have given link.

Comment: Ill provide u the code for that but itll b really long ... hold on .. c my answer ...

Comment: @Pinky Hey pinky, Have u got this solution. If u got please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Here The images are being picked from the PhotoLibrary and then using gestures they are being moved, zoomed etc. I am using All the gestures to help u do virtually any panning, pinching and rotating of any image you put.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
imageCollage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 80, 150, 150)];
[imageCollage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
imageCollage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,imageCollage.frame                                                          .size.width, imageCollage.frame.size.height)];
holderView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
holderView.clipsToBounds = YES;
imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
[imageview setImage:imageCollage.image];
[holderView addSubview:imageview];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

DeleteImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[DeleteImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DeleteRed.png"]];
[holderView addSubview:DeleteImage];
DeleteImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[DeleteImage addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

[BaseView addSubview:holderView];

[Trash setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"12456977871712665073hrum_trash.svg.med.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

   -(void)scale:(id)sender
   {
BaseView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[BaseView bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;
}   
CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
  }

  -(void)rotate:(id)sender
  {

[BaseView bringSubviewToFront:[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    lastRotation = 0.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

[[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
   }

   -(void)move:(id)sender
  {
[[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
BaseView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[BaseView bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
    firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

[[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (.20*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
    CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (.20*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

        if(finalX < 0) {

            finalX = 0;
        }

        else if(finalX > 260) {

            finalX = 260;
        }

        if(finalY < 0) {

            finalY = 0;
        }

        else if(finalY > 416) {

            finalY = 416;
        }
    }

    else {

        if(finalX < 0) {

            finalX = 0;
        }

        else if(finalX > 416) {

            finalX = 260;
        }

        if(finalY < 0) {

            finalY = 0;
        }

        else if(finalY > 260) {

            finalY = 416;
        }
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
   }



      -(void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recogniser
      {
    NSLog(@"%@",recogniser.view);
    [Trash setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash_bin_recycle_quit_terminate_error_cancel_close_exit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[[recogniser view] superview] removeFromSuperview];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    return ![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]];
}
```

Any queries about the cod please feel free to ask :)... Happy Coding ..

Comment: Hey I have already implemented it but after getting many images from Elcimagepicker How can I put it together in a shape like heart shape. I don't want to rotate or move that pic. just want to put them in a purticular shape.  To show my all pic in a shape.

Comment: @Pinky you want it arranged from before or do you want the user to arrange it on runtime ?

Comment: yes, I want to put all selected images directly to selected shape. don't want user to rotate or move it. like in app I have given in link.

Comment: How many images are u selecting ? Coz only a fixed number of images u can put them in some shape

Comment: its not limited. but I want to put it together.if there is no space in shape then it will be put on each other. I search it many times but it may be some CGRect code. so I could not do it.

Comment: There must be some limited number of images bcoz for putting into that particular shape u should have a minimum requirement....

Comment: @Gill: Can you provide the full code. lot of errors are showing !!

Comment: In wat context do u want the code @Mr.Roy ? Please outline your issue to me first :) ...

Comment: I just applied your code to my program wherein I am making a collage of images picked from a pickerView, but errors are coming !! So if you dont mind can you gimme the ful code, or atleast a link to a similar tutorial, it wil be a grrt help bro !!

Comment: So you simply want to display some images into a collage ... not in any specific shape right ? Show me your code in that case or tell me where the errors are taking place ...

Comment: @Gill Yes I want to change shape also. A random Collage. What is this "Trash" in your code? !! isn't there any tutorial for my help !!

Comment: @Mr.Roy The Trash is a UIImage which is attached on top of any image picked from the photo library , when tapped this trash image will remove itself and the picked image. that is why removeFromSuperview is used. I made this code myself coz i cudnt find a tutorial for it myself :) ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17817/discussion-between-mr-roy-and-gill)

Answer (score 0):

If you have little experience with Core Graphics and want to programmatically generate those kinds of shapes, I would recommend you use a Mac app called [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/).

You can use it to draw your shapes, and it generates the corresponding Objective-C drawing code.